# How can i save the positions of slider in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, slider

i'm trying to save slider values on quit. Right now i can save only value:

```
public void SaveSettingsValues() {
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("MouseSens", MouseSensitivitySlider.value);
}
```

How can i save position of slider children object, like Handle Slide Area?

Comment: Why do you need to save it? Just set the slider value on the next start and things like the position of the handle area will be set automatically.

Comment: The value should give you the position